# Reliable way to relate emails in an email thread in SendGrid

Tags: email, webhooks, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

**Summary**
How can [SendGrid's Inbound Parse](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook) and [send mail SDK](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send) be used to receive emails, respond then associate each new message in thread with the original email?

Setting the `replyTo` in the sending email is nice but isn't reliable as the user may respond to to other messages in the thread, such as the original message and hence miss this.

One solution we're trying is using message headers to associate emails by message ID. Not sure if this is reliable though?

This question is about best practice and finding the most reliable option.

This question doesn't apply to SendGrid alone but emails in general.

#### Code Snippets

shammelburg has a [nice setup here](https://github.com/shammelburg/express-sendgrid-inbound-parse) that can be used to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are usually something each email client can handle differently to visualize the items in your inbox. So it's not a standard you can rely on and not related to anything you can configure in the inbound parse or the client when you send an email.

Gmail and other large providers usually group emails that have the same subject line as the original email with a "RE: " prefix.

Here's an example: The subject of the original email: "Hello World" The subject line of your response: "RE: Hello World".

Comment: Hi IObert, I meant associating in the webhook when we receive any follow-up emails

Comment: I got the question but the answer is no. The webhook just takes care of the delivery to your app but not of the relation to another email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

This question isn't necessarily about SendGrid and more about emails in general then and hence it's still open